# Is this Vulkan code to found appropriate memory types for allocation safe?

Tags: vulkan

In Vulkan you create a buffer, then ask it what types of memory are appropriate for the buffer you created. It returns an integer type, a set of flags, with a bit set corresponding to which memory type is appropriate. So if you get back 0100100 then candidate memory types to allocate in are 2 and 5. The code takes the integer 1, and << left shifts each time to check if that bit is set. My understanding is that it's undefined to shift past the width of the type, so I guess that means that for an int, if we assume 32 bit size, shifting like this if undefined if we shift more than (32 - 1) = 31, right? This is the code to find the first appropriate memory type to allocate in:

```
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < memProperties.memoryTypeCount; i++) {
    if ((typeFilter & (1 << i))
    {
        return i;
    }
}
```

'memoryTypeCount' is queried at runtime and is unknown when compiling. I'm not sure whether 'memoryTypeCount' will ever be greater than 31, but if it is then this will fail? Does Vulkan specify that the max number of memory types is 31? 32? Isn't this dependent on the GPU? The same thing kind of goes for heap types, I've got a static array set at size 16, I hope my program never encounters more.

Comment: "*but if it is then this will fail*" How big is the bitfield?

Comment: @NicolBolas Well my Vulkan header uses a uint32_t as the bitfield flags. And in the memory properties the the memoryHeaps is a [16] array and the memoryTypes is a [32] array. I'm assuming that Vulkan only allows this many heaps and types, therefore I'm safe in assuming there won't be more?